# Is there any algorithm to solve counting change for finite number of denominations?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I know the algorithm to solve the coin change problem for infinite number of denominations but is there any algorithm for finite number of denominations using DP?

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us which "coin change problem" you're talking about.  There are several different ones when I google it.

Comment: the coin change problem is that there are some coins such as 1, 2, 3, 5 etc. And there are infinite number of them. And i have to make 20 with these coins, and I have to take as minimum as possible. But the problem I am talking about has finite number of coins.

Comment: if you use only the base (1,2,3,5) you could implement a greedy algorithm (more efficient) as this base is canonical

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Modify the initial algorithm such that, when it's about to add a coin that would exceed the number of available coins of that denomination, it doesn't, instead. Then it will only print the valid combos.

Another, more simple way is: run the algorithm without bounds, then filter the output based on what combinations are invalid. Thinking of it this way makes it really obvious that the problem is indeed solvable.